# Ruby concatenate two methods

Tags: ruby

I literally just started with Ruby so please do not hate for this question if I'm doing something really silly.

What I'd like to achieve is to have two methods:

```
def method1()
 puts "foo"
end

def method2()
 puts "bar"
end
```

and then I would like to put these two together as such

```
method1 + method2
```

to print out foo bar

Is this possible in ruby to do such a thing?

Comment: Avoid methods with side effects if it's possible. In your case it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than printing the values inside the functions, you should *return* the values from the functions.

```
def method1()
 "foo"
end

def method2()
 "bar"
end
```

Now you can do any of the following

```
puts method1 # Prints "foo"
puts method2 # Prints "bar"
puts method1 + method2 # Prints "foobar"
```

Having the `puts` inside the method only allows the caller to do one thing with that method, namely print out the value it produces. Returning a string from the method allows callers to do whatever they please: print it, concatenate it, capitalize it, or anything else under the sun.

Comment: Hi thank you for your prompt answer. That works nicely. Thank you. But what if I want to add a space, let's say
```
puts method1 + " " + method2
```
I'm getting a Type Error. I know that I can return "foo " but I have a case where I need to do it this way. The error is +': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError) and I can't find anything anywhere about concatenating methods with strings on the web

Comment: In my case for some reason I had to convert the method to string so this worked for me
method1.to_s + " " + method2.to_s

Comment: With string interpolation: `puts "#{method1} #{method2}"`